# IOS tapping and gestures

Tags: ios, iphone

Is It possible for IOS app to produce Taps/Gestures on the IOS system including other APPs?
possibly using the switch control accessibility feautures?
I looked around and this seems not to be possible, any ideas?

Trying to develop an APP.

Comment: No, it is not possible

Comment: thought so, is it possible to control specific apps?

Comment: No. Apps are contained n a sandbox and cannot interact with other apps. When your app is not onscreen then, aside from some limited background modes, it is not executing